# HOW TO SERVE CERTAIN ADS TO MOBILE DEVICES

Tags: ee2

WE ARE A RESPONSIVE DESIGN  I template for all sizes.  Yet we are switching up out ads, and want to serve one set of ads for a desktop and laptop and 1 type for mobile devices.  How do i go about doing this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to install the useful [Mo'variables](https://github.com/rsanchez/mo_variables) add-on - which provides an `{if is_mobile}` conditional flag.  You could use this to determine what your template does for mobile vs. desktop.

HTH

Comment: Thank you.  I knew there had to be an answer I just spent, a few days trying to figure what I was looking for.,. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in CSS with Bootstrap. Example:

```
<div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none">
Visible only on large viewport
</div>

<div class="d-block d-sm-none">
Visible only on extra small viewport
</div>
```

More at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/.